# Insert и select-запрос в таблицу, связанную FOREIGN KEY с другой таблицей

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь понять как добавить данные в таблицу, но проблема в том, что там есть FOREIGN KEY.

Схема базы данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема:

Чтобы создать нового агента или же клиента - нужно сначала заполнить данные в таблицу Person, потом получить ID, который она выдала, этот ID связать с ID Agent или Client.

Пробовал сделать через стандартный DataSource в Visual Studio, тупо перетащив таблицу, получив вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал InnerJoin'ом с помощью

```
TableAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {TableName} INNER JOIN {TableJoinName} ON {TableName}.Id = {TableJoinName}.ID", TableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Connection);
```

Но тогда стандартный способ обновления данных по DataGridView не работает, тупо ничего не обновляет / добавляет.

Как это можно проще сделать?

Нужно что-то типа представления (подставление Имя и Фамилии вместо ID'а, как минимум), но с возможностью обновлять данные.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: _сначала заполнить данные в таблицу Person, потом получить ID, который она выдала, этот ID связать с ID Agent или Client_ - вот как написали, так и делайте. Сперва `insert`, потом `select`, потом снова `insert`.

Comment: Можно обойтись без промежуточного `select`, если ключи задаются вручную или если они генерируются в БД, тогда использовать `scope_identity()`. См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37909451/5045688